# Flutter save a network mp3 file to local directory

Tags: dart, flutter

I am new to Flutter and Dart ,Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Future<dynamic> downloadFile(String url) async {
 String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
  File file = new File('$dir/$filename');
  var request = await http.get(url,);
  var bytes = await request.bodyBytes;//close();
  await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
  print(file.path);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you download your file you can use [path_provider](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_provider)  plugin to access device storage and save your file there.

I would recommend the Document directory which can be accessed using `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` to save your mp3 file.